# ML - reversing a string;

Tags: string, ml

i'm building a function:

```
val recur = fn : string * int -> string;
```

Which gets a string and its size and return it reversed;

But somewhat it doesn't work for me as I built it, can anybody point me the problem and maybe give a little correction :

```
fun recur (s:string, sz:int) = if sz = 1 then substring(s,sz-1,sz-1) else substring(s,sz-1,sz-1) ^ recur(s,sz-1);
```

It should do the work, but for example for operating:

```
recur("ab",2);
```

It return only **"b"**.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for `substring` is the starting index, and the third is the length you want.

When `sz = 1`, `substring(s,sz-1,sz-1)` is `substring(s,0,0)`, which is the empty string.

There's a similar problem on the recursion, as you may try to take more characters than possible.
You only want a one-character substring every time:

```
fun recur (s:string, sz:int) = if sz = 1 
                               then substring(s, 0, 1) 
                               else substring(s, sz-1, 1) ^ recur(s, sz-1);
```

String manipulation is often easier if you convert to a list of characters, though:

```
fun recur (s:string) = String.implode(List.rev(String.explode s));
```